# I'm trying to add to an array of objects that is broken into two inputs in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, next.js, spread

So I have an array of objects where the keys are 'cost' and 'service' called estimate. You can add to the array by clicking 'Add' which adds a new index (i) to the array. The issue is on the first cycle I get a good array of {'cost': 2500, 'service': "commercial cleaning"} (imgSet-1) but when I add another item it completely erases the array and sets only one of the nested objects key and value. (imgSet-2). This is the outcome I'm looking for once the state has been saved (imgSet-3) I have tried going with @RubenSmn approach but then I receive this error. (imgSet-4)

imgSet-1 *********
[Adding an initial service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6kzF.png)
[Outcome of the initial service addition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmOpH.png)

---

imgSet-2 *********
[Adding the second service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34qDf.png)
[Outcome of the second service addition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpsTQ.png)

---

imgSet-3 *********
[image: Finale rendered outcome]

---

imgSet-4 *********
[image: Error after trying dif approach]

---

Below is the code for the part of the page where you can add services and the output of the text inputs.

```
const [estimate, setEstimate] = useState([]);

{[...Array(numServices)].map((e, i) => {
            return (
              <div key={i} className="flex justify-between">
                <div>
                  <NumericTextBoxComponent
                    format="c2"
                    name={`cost-${i}`}
                    value={estimate?.items?.["cost"]?.[i]}
                    change={(e) =>
                      setEstimate({ ...estimate, items: [{...estimate?.items?.[i],cost: e?.value}]})
                    }
                    placeholder='Price'
                    floatLabelType="Auto"
                    data-msg-containerid="errorForCost"
                  />
                </div>
                <div>
                  <DropDownListComponent
                    showClearButton
                    fields={{ value: "id", text: "service" }}
                    name={`service-${i}`}
                    value={estimate?.items?.["service"]?.[i]}
                    change={(e) =>
                      setEstimate({ ...estimate, items: [{...estimate?.items?.[i],service: e?.value}]})
                    }
                    id={`service-${i}`}
                    floatLabelType="Auto"
                    data-name={`service-${i}`}
                    dataSource={estimateData?.services}
                    placeholder="Service"
                    data-msg-containerid="errorForLead"
                  ></DropDownListComponent>
                  <div id="errorForLead" />
                </div>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </form>
        <button onClick={() => setNumServices(numServices + 1)}>Add</button>
```

I have tried multiple variations of spread operators but I can't seem to get it to work. My expected result would be:

```
estimate:{
  items: [
    {'cost': 2500, 'service': 'Commercial Clean'},
    {'cost': 500, 'service': 'Bathroom Clean'},
    {'cost': 180, 'service': 'Apartment Clean'},
    {etc.}
]
}
```

Comment: Please provide `numServices` detail. How do you get and fill?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial state is an array which is not the object you're setting in the `change` handlers. You can have an initial state like this.

```js
const [estimate, setEstimate] = useState({ items: [] });
```

You're not adding back the **old** items of the state when you're setting the new state.

```js
setEstimate({
  ...estimate,
  items: [{ ...estimate?.items?.[i], cost: e?.value }],
  // should be something like
  // items: [...estimate.items, { ...estimate.items?.[i], cost: e?.value }],
});
```

But you can't do that since it will create a new object in your items array every time you change a value.

I made this dynamic `handleChange` function which you can use for you state changes. The first if statement is to check if the itemIndex is already in the items array. If not, create a new item with the `propertyName` and the `value`

```js
const handleChange = (e, itemIndex, propertyName) => {
  const newValue = e?.value;

  setEstimate((prevEstimate) => {
    if (prevEstimate.items.length <= itemIndex) {
      const newItem = { [propertyName]: newValue };
      return {
        ...prevEstimate,
        items: [...prevEstimate.items, newItem]
      };
    }

    // loop over old items
    const newItems = [...prevEstimate.items].map((item, idx) => {
      // if index' are not the same just return the old item
      if (idx !== itemIndex) return item;
      // else return the item with the new service
      return { ...item, [propertyName]: newValue };
    });

    return {
      ...prevEstimate,
      items: newItems,
    };
  });
};
```

For the Service dropdown, you can do the same for the Cost just change the **property name**

```js
<DropDownListComponent
  ...
  value={estimate.items[i]?.service}
  change={(e) => handleChange(e, i, "service")}
  ...
></DropDownListComponent>
```

See here a simplified [live version](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-ride-sokx86)

Comment: TypeError: (intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value) is not iterable

Comment: That is the error I get when I try to add anything.

Comment: @mattr534 I think that happens because of the `value` property not working properly, I updated my answer

Comment: It still is not working. I believe it's something to do with the initial value which is just null.

Comment: Please edit your question and update it with the extra information

Comment: I'm not sure what else to say. I added some info like what the rendered outcome should be and that I start with an empty state.

Comment: I also added an image of the error that pops up when I use your approach.

Comment: Did you try it with the new initial state, I updated my answer with @mattr534?

Comment: Hey sorry, I had to go out of town, trying it now!

Comment: So every time I add to the estimates it ends up being an empty array.

This is the result
`{
    "estimate": {
        "items": []
    }
}`

Comment: Yes you're correct, the answer was missing an edge case in which there were no items yet. And so no items to map over :(. I updated my answer and added a simplified live version @mattr534

Comment: So I kept the code for the value and change the same but everything else worked! Thanks man, you are a lifesaver!!! 

`value={estimate?.items?.[i]?.service} change={(e) => handleChange(e, i, "service")}`